# VSCode won't comment with keyboard shortcut or even from menu (python)

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I can go up to Edit -> Toggle Line Comment and click it, or I can use the shortcut (default: ctrl + /), and it does nothing.  I can't find a setting that turns on or off comments anywhere?  Obviously I can go to the front of the line and put a # there, but the keyboard shortcut should work?

Comment: Try disabling all extensions and see if it works.  Secondly, search your keybindings.json to see if it's binding has been negated.

Comment: I only have the one extension (the python one from MSFT).  I tried disabling/reloading - didn't do anything.  I looked in keybindings - it's all defaults.  The section that I'd edit is blank.